# Run python process (using Pool of Multiprocessing ) parallel for batch

Tags: python, shell, optimization, multiprocessing

See, I need to write a code for ~quarter million input files to run on batch. I saw this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20416/python-parallelization-using-popen

I can't figure it out how to implement this in my code.

**What I want**

- I want to give each process specific number of cores or in other words, specific number of processes only can run at certain time.
- If one process is finished another one should takes its place.

**My code (using subprocess)**

**Main.py**

```
import subprocess
import os
import multiprocessing
import time
MAXCPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

try:
    cp = int(raw_input("Enter Number of CPU's to use (Total %d) = "%MAXCPU))
    assert cp <= MAXCPU
except:
    print "Bad command taking all %d cores"%MAXCPU
    cp =MAXCPU  # set MAXCPU as CPU

list_pdb = [i for i in os.listdir(".") if i.endswith(".pdb")]  # Input PDB files
assert len(list_pdb) != 0

c = {}
d = {}
t = {}

devnull = file("Devnull","wb")
for each in range(0, len(list_pdb), cp):   # Number of cores in Use = 4
    for e in range(cp):
        if each + e < len(list_pdb):
            args = ["sh", "Child.sh", list_pdb[each + e], str(cp)]
            p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False,
                stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
            c[p.pid] = p
            print "Started Process : %s" % list_pdb[each + e]
    while c:
        print c.keys()
        pid, status = os.wait()
        if pid in c:
            print "Ended Process"
            del c[pid]
devnull.close()
```

**Child.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sh grand_Child.sh
sh grand_Child.sh
sh grand_Child.sh
sh grand_Child.sh
# Some heavy processes with $1
```

**grand_Child.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of the code using `multiprocessing.Pool`.  It's a lot simpler, as the module does nearly all the work!

This version also does:

- lots of logging, when a proc starts/ends
- prints how many files will be processed
- lets you process more than numcpus at a time

Often when running multiprocess jobs, it's best to run *more* processes than CPUs. Different procs will wait on I/O, vs waiting for CPU.  Often people run 2n+1, so for a 4 proc system they run 2*4+1 or 9 procs for a job.  (I generally hardcode "5" or "10" until there's a reason to change, I'm lazy that way :) )

Enjoy!

### source

```
import glob
import multiprocessing
import os
import subprocess

MAXCPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
TEST = False

def do_work(args):
    path,numproc = args
    curproc = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print curproc, "Started Process, args={}".format(args)
    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    cmd = ["sh", "Child.sh", path, str(numproc)]
    if TEST:
        cmd.insert(0, 'echo')
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(
            cmd, shell=False,
            stderr=devnull,
        )
    finally:
        print curproc, "Ended Process"

if TEST:
    cp = MAXCPU
    list_pdb = glob.glob('t*.py')
else:
    cp = int(raw_input("Enter Number of processes to use (%d CPUs) = " % MAXCPU))
    list_pdb = glob.glob('*.pdb') # Input PDB files
# assert cp <= MAXCPU

print '{} files, {} procs'.format(len(list_pdb), cp)
assert len(list_pdb) != 0

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cp)
print pool.map(
    do_work, [ (path,cp) for path in list_pdb ],
)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

### output

```
27 files, 4 procs
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> Started Process, args=('tdownload.py', 4)
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> Ended Process
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> Started Process, args=('tscapy.py', 4)
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)> Ended Process
```

Comment: You're welcome @DevashishDas.  To help you along, check my other answers on Stack Overflow -- about half are `multiprocessing` related: http://stackoverflow.com/users/143880/shavenwarthog?tab=answers&sort=newest

Comment: Can you tell how can I get the stdoutput to a file from this?

Comment: @DevashishDas: parse the output of `subprocess.check_output(...)`

Comment: How to add subprocess with multiprocessing.Pool.map?

Comment: @DevashishDas Pool(num) starts with a certain number of processes which last "forever."  You can't add nor delete procs in the pool.

Comment: Then how it will catch the output with subprocess.check_output(...)

Comment: @DevashishDas update your code and post another question